# Azure Search doesn't seem to handle unicode punctuators

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an Azure Search index with a bunch of text entries. I've observed that if the index contains an entry like "AI's" (with the Unicode apostrophe character 8217), searching for the word 'AI' fails to return the result. The indexed should handle punctuators - including Unicode variants. Searching for "John" should return an item that has "John's." Please confirm if this is a known bug and if so when it will be fixed.

Expecting to find "AI's" when I search for "AI" (where the apostrophe is a Unicode character 8217). The item is not returned as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

can you confirm what analyzer you are using in your index? We support many analyzers that will break down your search terms and document terms into different tokens. For example, if your content is in English, you could use the en.microsoft analyzer, which should split your "AI's" term into two tokens -> "AI" and "AI's".

More info on analyzers here ->

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-analyzers
and here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-language-analyzers